# Regex matching for optional strings

Tags: regex

I am trying to come up with a smallest regex possible for extracting parts of a string with the last section being an optional one. The string will look something like:

```
jack:Bill(23):Space Force (23, Apple;Orange)
```

or

```
jack:Bill(23):Space Force
```

I need to extract as follows:

```
Jack
Bill(23)
Space Force
23
Apple;Orange
```

The last 2 items may or may not appear based on the source string. I am trying with a regex like:

```
(.*?):(.*?):(.*?)(\\(([0-9]+),([^\\)]*)?\\))?
```

But this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with `(.*?):(.*?):([^\\(]*)(\\(([0-9]+), ([^\\)]*)?\\))?`

Comment: But this will not capture the `Apple;Orange` part.

Comment: The ([^\\)]*) part after the ',' does.

Comment: @Mandy8055 [**This**](https://regex101.com/r/rHjAUE/2) is the correct regex test.